# Which subset is this null space of a matrix from?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A$, give the integer $n$ such that Nul $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$$A:\begin{pmatrix}
5&-6&0&-1\\
-4&6&7&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, from what I've read is that the null space of a matrix is the span of its free variables, and since $A$ has free variables, precisely 2 free variables, shouldn't the null space then be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Instead, it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{4}$ which I don't quite understand.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you get that the null space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$? by the way, clearly $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. In other words, the null space is guaranteed to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: No, $\mathbb R^2$ is NOT a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$, it is not even a subset. The only thing we can say is that we can identify $\mathbb R^2$ with the subset $\{(x,y,0,0): x,y \in \mathbb R\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$.

Answer (score 1):

The null space of a matrix $A$ is defined to be the vectors $v$ such that $Av=0$. So in order to find out what $n$ is we have to think about the length of the vector $v$ that can be plugged in to the matrix-vector-multiplication. By the rules for matrix vector multiplication we know that the vector $v$ must have as many components as the matrix $A$ has columns, in this case it has to be $n=4$ because otherwise the multiplication $Av$ is not defined.